# InternetCheckConnection in VB6 returning false

Tags: vb6

I'm trying to come up with a VB6 test app that calls [InternetCheckConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384346(v=vs.85).aspx).

In my test app, InternetCheckConnection always returns false regardless of the URL I use.  I copied and pasted this code from a larger spaghetti-code app, but in the spaghetti-code, InternetCheckConnection seems to work fine, returns true.

Is there some other function I have to call first in order for InternetCheckConnection to work?

Comment: Let's link to the MSDN topic for [InternetGetConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384346(v=vs.85).aspx). Linking makes the internet better :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the InternetGetConnectedState function.

```
Private Declare Function InternetGetConnectedState Lib "wininet.dll" (ByRef lpSFlags As Long, ByVal dwReserved As Long) As Long

Dim blnInternetConnected as Boolean
Dim Flags as long

blnInternetConnected = InternetGetConnectedState(Flags, 0&)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get InternetCheckConnection to work correctly by including the full address for a website, including "http://". For example, using "www.google.com" returned False, but "http://www.google.com" returned true.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, in the "spaghetti-code" app, InternetCheckConnection is relying on the state of some global variable you are not aware of. Is that possible?